# R: number in a txt file split up by line

Tags: r

I have a problem in reading a .txt in to R.

The data is something like this:

```
68 89 103 1

37 8 103  9

78 93 8 12

3 50
```

I used readLine() in R and came up with a list. But when I compare it to the raw data, I find that , for example, the last "1" in the first line is not 1, it should be connected to the second line, which make the number to e 137, instead of 1 and 37. I think this data is split by " ". If I use readLine(), I manually split up the lines. How could I correctly read it?
And, number 9 is not connect to 78 since at the beginning of line 3, there is a space. number 12 is connected with 3 to form 123, since there is no space before 3.

Thanks. I even don't know how to search my problem in Google. Don't know how to express it.

```
182 63 68 152 130 134 145 152 98 152 182 88 95 105 130 137 167 152 81 71 84 126 134 152 116 130 91 63 68 84 95 152 105 152 63
 102 152 63 77 112 140 77 119 152 161 167 105 112 145 161 182 152 81 95 84 91 102 108 130 134 91

1 2 1 4 3 6 1 1 5 2 1 5 2 3 4 5 5 1 2 6 1

63 102 119 161 161 172 179 88 91 95 105 112 119 119 137 145 167 172 91 98 108 112 134 137 161 161 179 71 174 95 105 134 134 1
37 140 145 150 150 68 68 130 137 77 95 112 137 161 174 81 84 126 134 161 161 174 68 77 98 102 102 102 112 88 88 91 98 112 134
 134 137 137 140 140 152 152 77 179 112 71 71 74 77 112 116 116 140 140 167 77 95 126 150 88 126 130 130 134 63 74 84 84 88 9
1 95 108 134 137 179 81 88 105 116 123 140 145 152 161 161 179 88 95 112 119 126 126 150 157 179 68 68 84 102 105 119 123 123
 137 161 179 182 140 152 182 182 81 63 88 134 84 134 182


7 11 9 2 9 4 6 7 6 1 13 2 1 10 4 5 11 11 9 12 1 3 1 3 3
```

Basically, what I am doing now is:
For example, the vector:

```
ind <- c(7, 11, 9, 2 ,9 ,4 ,6, 7, 6 ,1, 13, 2 ,1 ,10 ,4 ,5 ,11 ,11, 9 ,12, 1, 3 ,1, 3 ,3)
```

indicates that the block of number above should be split up according to the length specified by the vector. I know I can split up a vector by

```
split(vector, rep(1:length(ind), ind))
```

However, the problem is I can't read the block of number correctly.

Comment: I copy the data in the code editor. I think it is the shape as you can see. There is no way to use read.table()

Comment: it's a txt file. I havn't tried scan(). I will check the function right now.

Comment: I tried to use scan(), but it automatically split up by \n and " ". I don't want \n as a space to split.

Comment: Have a look at `sub("\\s+", "", r[nzchar(r)])` where `r` is the object read in from `readLines()` It removes all the erroneous spaces and new-lines.

Comment: Thank you Richard. I will try it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conditions you described, i.e. if there is a `space` at the beginning of line after you read the file with `readLines`, then the last number in the previous line should be joined with the first number of the current line.

Using your second example (I didn't understand the `ind` though)

```
lines1 <- readLines(n=10)
182 63 68 152 130 134 145 152 98 152 182 88 95 105 130 137 167 152 81 71 84 126 134 152 116 130 91 63 68 84 95 152 105 152 63
 102 152 63 77 112 140 77 119 152 161 167 105 112 145 161 182 152 81 95 84 91 102 108 130 134 91

1 2 1 4 3 6 1 1 5 2 1 5 2 3 4 5 5 1 2 6 1

63 102 119 161 161 172 179 88 91 95 105 112 119 119 137 145 167 172 91 98 108 112 134 137 161 161 179 71 174 95 105 134 134 1
37 140 145 150 150 68 68 130 137 77 95 112 137 161 174 81 84 126 134 161 161 174 68 77 98 102 102 102 112 88 88 91 98 112 134
 134 137 137 140 140 152 152 77 179 112 71 71 74 77 112 116 116 140 140 167 77 95 126 150 88 126 130 130 134 63 74 84 84 88 9
1 95 108 134 137 179 81 88 105 116 123 140 145 152 161 161 179 88 95 112 119 126 126 150 157 179 68 68 84 102 105 119 123 123
 137 161 179 182 140 152 182 182 81 63 88 134 84 134 182

 lines2 <- lines1[lines1!=''] #remove blank lines
 indx <- grep("^ ", lines2) #create a numeric index for lines that start with a space
 indx1 <- indx-1 #index that is one above the previous `indx`
 lines2[indx1] <- paste0(lines2[indx1], gsub("^\\s+", "", lines2[indx])) #paste the lines together using the two indexes 
 lines3 <- lines2[-indx] #remove the lines that belong to the first index

 lines3
 #[1] "182 63 68 152 130 134 145 152 98 152 182 88 95 105 130 137 167 152 81 71 84 126 134 152 116 130 91 63 68 84 95 152 105 152 63102 152 63 77 112 140 77 119 152 161 167 105 112 145 161 182 152 81 95 84 91 102 108 130 134 91"                             
 #[2] "1 2 1 4 3 6 1 1 5 2 1 5 2 3 4 5 5 1 2 6 1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 #[3] "63 102 119 161 161 172 179 88 91 95 105 112 119 119 137 145 167 172 91 98 108 112 134 137 161 161 179 71 174 95 105 134 134 1"                                                                                                                            
 #[4] "37 140 145 150 150 68 68 130 137 77 95 112 137 161 174 81 84 126 134 161 161 174 68 77 98 102 102 102 112 88 88 91 98 112 134134 137 137 140 140 152 152 77 179 112 71 71 74 77 112 116 116 140 140 167 77 95 126 150 88 126 130 130 134 63 74 84 84 88 9"
 #[5] "1 95 108 134 137 179 81 88 105 116 123 140 145 152 161 161 179 88 95 112 119 126 126 150 157 179 68 68 84 102 105 119 123 123137 161 179 182 140 152 182 182 81 63 88 134 84 134 182"
```